# Axios get request with multiple parameters passed to mysql query

Tags: javascript, express, get, axios

I have an api that fetches user data from a mysql database. I have set up an express route as follows:

```js
module.exports = (app, mysql) => {
  app.get('/api/users/:id', function(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id
    mysql.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = "${id}"`, function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results)
    });

    mysql.end();
  })
}
```

I then have an axios service that fetches the user data as follows:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  getUserInfo: async(teamMemberId) => {
    const url = `/api/users/${teamMemberId}`;
    let res = await axios.get(url);
    return res.data || [];
  }
}
```

I'm able to pass a userId in the url of the get request `(like /api/users/jdoe)`, and it returns data for that user as expected.  However, I want to be able to able to pass multiple users to this request, and would like the query to be something like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')`.

How can I accomplish this using axios?

Comment: the solution would simply be to pass the array of user id in the request and accordingly use that array to frame your MySQL query on the server

Comment: You can pass the array as body in axios request and use IN clause in your query to fetch the data for multiple users at once

Comment: Does the url need to change? Do I still have to pass `:id` in the url `'/api/users/:id'` ?